# How to enable services in beaglebone black?

Tags: service, daemon, splash-screen, beagleboneblack

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/psplash

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

job for .service failed because the control process exited with an error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is shell script to make service of python code.
It will start the execution at startup,

```
[Unit]
Description= Python First Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/debian/serv_demo.py
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this example and it worked well for my BBB:

https://gist.github.com/tstellanova/7323116